# Cant figure out how to use childs in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ok so for about a week now i have been digging through the internet for help with addChild and its uses. So what im trying to do is have a bullet in the library and have a keybind where it adds a bullet to the screen. Every time I try the var _bullet:Bullet; or _bullet:Bullet=new Bullet(); i get a error saying bullet isnt defined. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you have linked your movieclip in the library...

Answer (score 1):

Your object needs to be a `class` to be called by the code. Linkage may be set by right-clicking your symbol from the library > Properties > Export for actionScript > Class:`Bullet`.

To create an instance of your `class` Bullet, and add it to the `display list`:

```
var _bullet:Bullet = new Bullet();
this.addChild(_bullet);
```